# How to remove unmatched auto-complete results?

Tags: auto-complete-mode

Now auto-complete show list of values, used in other files, not in current, for example:

[image: Wrong autocomplete lines]

[image: js2-mode]

I use latest versions of all packages from MELPA, and my **.emacs** contain this strings for set settings:

```
(global-auto-complete-mode t)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'py-autopep8-enable-on-save)
(setq jedi:complete-on-dot t)
(setq ac-auto-start 1)
;; More for tern, js2 and other...
```

I do'not change settings for **auto-complete** with **sustomize**.

How to remove unmatched values from auto-completion list?

Comment: That must be a dabbrev-style backend which picks not only words from your current buffer, but from other buffers as well.  Have you had a look at the currently active backends for AC yet?

Comment: jedi, ac-emmet, ac-html, ac-js2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude some extra auto-complete sources in python-mode

For example:

```
   (add-hook 'python-mode-hook
             (lambda ()
               (delq 'ac-source-dictionary ac-sources)
               (delq 'ac-source-abbrev ac-sources)
               (delq 'ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers ac-sources)))
```

Hope this help.

Djangoliv

Comment: Hello! Can I see your .emacs for more experience?

Comment: Here my site with comment in french of my .emacs: http://djangoliv.alwaysdata.net/articles 
For python: http://djangoliv.alwaysdata.net/articles/emacs/python/pythonel/

For jedi: http://djangoliv.alwaysdata.net/articles/emacs/python/jedi/
The site is not up to date but not so old...

Answer (score 0):

```
customize-group auto-complete
```

Toggling **Ac User Comphist** to **nil**, saving and restart EMACS solve my problem.